# Multiple Database Connection Conflicts

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am using two database connections for application. The database connections established like below

```
$allrights = @mysql_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASS);
if (!$allrights) {
    //die("Database connection failed: " . mysql_error());
    echo "Check ServerHost,Username,Password Of the DataBase<br/>";
}
// 2. Select a database to use 
$db_select = @mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$allrights);
if (!$db_select) {
    //die("Database selection failed: " . mysql_error());
    echo "Incorrect DataBase Name";
}


// 1. Create a database connection
$readonly = @mysql_connect(DB_SERVER,READONLY_DB_USER,READONLY_DB_PASS);
if (!$readonly) {
    //die("Database connection failed: " . mysql_error());
    echo "Check ServerHost,Readonly-Username,Password Of the DataBase<br/>";
}
// 2. Select a database to use 
$db_select = @mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$readonly);
if (!$db_select) {
    //die("Database selection failed: " . mysql_error());
    echo "Incorrect DataBase Name";
}
```

But, while querying everything calls like

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM <tablename>");
```

Both connections are referring the same database. Which connections actually calls while querying the data?

Comment: have tried this?
@mysql_close($db_connection);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To specify the connection pass it as a parameter, for example:

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM <tablename>", $allrights);
```

If you don't what happens can be found in the documentation for [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php):

> If the link identifier is not specified, the last link opened by `mysql_connect()` is assumed.

Also, do pay attention to the big warning on red background:

> This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

Comment: This is the answer which answers `Which connections actually calls while querying the data?`

Answer (score 1):

When working with multiple database connections with [mysql_connect()](http://php.net/mysql_connect), you need to pass true as a 4th optional parameter (new_link) like below

```
$readonly = @mysql_connect(DB_SERVER,READONLY_DB_USER,READONLY_DB_PASS, true);
```

You also need to provide link identifier.

Quote from PHP Manual

> If a second call is made to mysql_connect() with the same arguments, no new link will be established, but instead, the link identifier of the already opened link will be returned. The new_link parameter modifies this behavior and makes mysql_connect() always open a new link, even if mysql_connect() was called before with the same parameters. In SQL safe mode, this parameter is ignored.

Note: Listen to other persons suggestions on using mysqli_*.

Answer (score 0):

Use the query like this:

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM <tablename>", $readonly); //the last parameter is the connection variable
```

**Note**: You have to use *mysqli_** which is the correct way of talking to `MySQL` from `PHP` because *mysql_* is gonna be deprecated soon.

**Warning**: As Hanky 웃 Panky mentioned using `@` will deprecate the warnings and you will end up getting no warning in cases of connection failures and absence of DB or some other issues with the database.

Comment: Fine, except OP is using `mysql_*`. We know he **should** be using `mysqli`, but this won't help him.

Comment: I know its already deprecated. But our existing application can have thousands of mysql_query(). I cant able to change the existing flow.

Comment: I think OP also needs to be told to avoid using those `@`, they are not helpful at all